# How do I simulate an SQL `timestamp` in plain old Ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime, timestamp, gmt

I am enforcing the output of a `datetime` as Zulu-Time by doing the following

```
object.updated_at.utc.iso8601 # => "2013-05-12T10:47:01Z"
```

This works fine for a `datetime` but when the object is persisting to a database as a `timestamp` instead I get

```
"Sun, 12 May 2013 10:47:01 UTC +00:00"
```

Which is not a Zulu Time string.

I can fix this by

```
object.updated_at.to_time.utc.iso8601
```

but I am now trying to unit test this fix, and I can't reproduce the `timestamp` format to test it.

How do I simulate an SQL `timestamp` such that `.utc.iso8601` returns "Sun, 12 May 2013 10:47:01 UTC +00:00", but without wrapping it in a whole mess of ActiveRecord etc?

Comment: Note that `Sun, 12 May...` is not a valid [ISO 8601 format date/time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) value...

Comment: weird right.  hence my trouble simulating it

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my problem was me not wearing my glasses and misreading my own test code.  I'd close the question except there is no 'closing the question because I forgot my glasses' option.

Comment: Off-topic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error caused by not wearing glasses. :)